# Create binray file in constructor

Tags: c++, file, class

I write a small `Store` that contain `Item`. I create two function one to print content of file one to sort the records and insert them back into file. With the initializer list it display correctly the content of file, but said that there is "Error with file". How to correct this issue and what is the best way to create a binary file in constructor

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Item
{
    char name[20];
    int code;
    float price;
    int quantity;

    Item() { code = 0, price = 0, quantity = 0;
    char name1[20] = { 0 }; strcpy_s(name, 20, name1);
    }
    Item(const char* name, int code, float price, int quantity)
    {
        strcpy_s(this->name, strlen(name) + 1, name);
        this->code = code;
        this->price = price;
        this->quantity = quantity;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Item& item)
    {
        os << "Name: " << item.name << endl;
        os << "code: " << item.code << endl;
        os << "price: " << item.price << endl;
        os << "quantity: " << item.quantity << endl << endl;
        return os;
    }
    bool operator!()
    {
        return code != 0;
    }
};
class Store
{
private:
    int size = 100;
    fstream file;
    string fileName;
public:
    Store(string fname);
    ~Store();
    Store& operator+=(Item& myItem);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Store&);
    void sortStore();
};
```

```
#include "Store.h"
Store::Store(string fname) : file(fname,ios::binary)
    {
    
        Item tmp;
        if (!file)
            cout << "Error with file" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            file.write((char*)&tmp, sizeof(Item));
        //file.close();
        file.open(fname, ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    }
Store::~Store()
{
    file.close();
}
Store& Store::operator+=(Item& myItem)
{
    file.write((char*)&myItem, sizeof(myItem));
    return (*this);
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Store& store)
{
    Item tmp;
    store.file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    for (int i = 0; i < store.size; i++)
    {
        store.file.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(Item));
        if (!tmp)
            cout << i << ": " <<  tmp;
    }
    return out;
}
void Store::sortStore()
{
    Item tmp;
    vector<Item> items;
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (!file.eof())
    {
        file.read((char*)&tmp, sizeof(Item));
        items.push_back(tmp);
    }
    sort(items.begin(), items.end(), [](Item& first, Item& second)
        {
            return first.code < second.code;
        });

    file.clear();
    remove("store.dat");
    Store("store.dat");

    file.seekp(0, ios::beg);
    
    for (auto it = items.begin(); it < items.end(); it++)
        file.write((char*)&(*it), sizeof(Item));
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Store ourStore("store.dat");
    Item apple("apple", 45, 12.2, 10);
    Item ananas("ananas", 12, 27, 10);
    Item strawberry("strawberry", 1, 24.2, 5);
    Item banana("banana",23,14.2, 12);
    ourStore.operator+=(apple);
    ourStore.operator+=(ananas);
    ourStore.operator+=(strawberry);
    ourStore.operator+=(banana);

    int choice = -1;
    while (choice != 0)
    {
        cout << "1.Sorting, 2 Print" << endl;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Sorting" << endl;
            ourStore.sortStore();
        case 2:
            cout << "Print" << endl;
            cout << ourStore << endl;
        }
        cin >> choice;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never open the `file` member.

Comment: @molbdnilo why? In the constructor I write file.open()

Comment: You also write `ofstream file(fname, ios::binary);`, which declares a local variable.

Comment: On a side note, the point of overloading operators is that it lets you write things like `ourStore += apple;`

Comment: @molbdnilo Does I have to write both in the constructor file.close() and after that openning it again ?

Comment: The local variable is not the same thing as your member variable. They just happen to have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `file` in `Store::Store` hides the member variable `Store::file`.

You want an initializer list:

```
Store::Store : file(fname, ios::binary)
{
// ...
```

Comment: Can you explain more what is the difference by writing this on an initializer list. Why when it is in the constructor, this doesn't work

Comment: @Ronyco123: Are you learning C++ from a good textbook? That's still the best way. Anyway, the difference is very large. The member initializer list determines which constructors are called for the members. Since you didn't have an initializer list, `Store::file` was constructed with the default constructor. That does not open the file.

Comment: I post now my constructor, what wrong with it

Comment: @Ronyco123: You've added your new question as an answer to an existing question. That's not going to work; people won't be looking for questions in the answers section. Instead, you should ask a new question. But before you do, make sure that you have two simple test cases: one with a local variable that does open the file, and one with a member initializer list that does not.